# ¿Cómo hacer un algoritmo en pseint que pueda sumar las columnas y las filas de una matriz rectangular?

Tags: matrices, pseint, vectores

Hola estoy aprendiendo programación y tengo que sumar las filas y las columnas de una matriz rectangular(una matriz que tiene un numero distinto de filas y de columnas), pero de momento solo puedo sumar de matrices cuadradas

```
Algoritmo sumaDeFilas
Dimension mat[3,3]
Para i<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
    Para j<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        mat[i,j]<- Aleatorio(0,30)
    FinPara
FinPara
Escribir "La matriz ingresada es ";
Para i<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer            
    Escribir ""; //Esto es solo para dar un poco de formato
    Para j<-0 Hasta 2 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Escribir Sin Saltar mat[i,j], " ";
    FinPara        
FinPara
Escribir "";
Para x<-0 Hasta 2 Hacer
    sumacolumnas<-0
    Para yy<-0 Hasta 2 Hacer
        sumacolumnas<-sumacolumnas+mat[yy,x]
    Fin Para
    Escribir "La suma de la columna ", x, " es ", sumacolumnas
Fin Para
Escribir ""
Para x<-0 Hasta 2 Hacer
    sumafilas<-0
    Para yy<-0 Hasta 2 Hacer
        sumafilas<-sumafilas+mat[x,yy]
    Fin Para
    Escribir "La suma de la fila ", x, " es ", sumafilas
Fin Para
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se pseint.. pero en cualquier lenguaje, para sumar matrices, haces un Para desde 0 hasta la cantidad de columnas, y dentro de ello un para desde 0 hasta la cantidad de filas.... supongo que pseint tiene una forma de saber la cantidad de filas y columnas.. y si no, cuando creas la matriz te quedas con esos valores...

Answer (score 0):

A continuación se muestra un ejemplo de cómo podría modificar su algoritmo para manejar matrices rectangulares:

```
Proceso sumaDeFilasYColumnas
    Definir filas Como Entero;
    Definir columnas Como Entero;
    Dimension mat[100];
    Definir mat Como Entero;
    Definir i Como Entero;
    Definir j Como Entero;
    Definir sumaFila Como Entero;
    Definir sumaColumna Como Entero;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese el número de filas: "; 
    Leer filas;
    Escribir "Ingrese el número de columnas: ";
    Leer columnas;
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta (filas - 1) Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Para j <- 0 Hasta (columnas - 1) Con Paso 1 Hacer
            mat[i * columnas + j] <- Aleatorio(0, 30);
        FinPara
    FinPara
    
    Escribir "La matriz ingresada es: ";
    Para i <- 0 Hasta (filas - 1) Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Para j <- 0 Hasta (columnas - 1) Con Paso 1 Hacer
            Si i = 0 Entonces
                Si j = 0 Entonces
                    Escribir "[" Sin Bajar;
                SiNo
                    Escribir "," Sin Bajar;
                FinSi
            Sino
                Escribir " " sin Bajar;
            FinSi
            Escribir mat[i * columnas + j] Sin Bajar;
        FinPara
        Si i < (filas - 1) Entonces
            Escribir "], ";
        SiNo
            Escribir "]";
        FinSi
    FinPara
    
    Escribir "";
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta columnas-1 Hacer
        sumaColumna <- 0;
        Para j <- 0 Hasta filas-1 Hacer
            sumaColumna <- sumaColumna + mat[j * columnas + i];
        FinPara
        Escribir "La suma de la columna ", i, " es: ", sumaColumna;
    FinPara
    
    Escribir "";
    
    Para i <- 0 Hasta filas-1 Hacer
        sumaFila <- 0;
        Para j <- 0 Hasta columnas-1 Hacer
            sumaFila <- sumaFila + mat[i * columnas + j];
        FinPara
        Escribir "La suma de la fila ", i, " es: ", sumaFila;
    FinPara
FinProceso
```

En esta versión, agregué dos variables para leer el número de filas y columnas de la matriz, y cambié la matriz de una matriz bidimensional a una matriz unidimensional. Las filas de la matriz se almacenan en elementos consecutivos de la matriz, con los primeros elementos de `columnas` correspondientes a la primera fila, los siguientes elementos de `columnas` correspondientes a la segunda fila, y así sucesivamente.

Para calcular la suma de una columna, he usado la fórmula `sumaColumna <- sumaColumna + mat[j * columnas + i]`, donde `i` es el índice de la columna y `j` es el índice de la fila. Esta fórmula calcula el índice del elemento en la matriz que corresponde a la intersección de la i-ésima columna y la j-ésima fila.

Para calcular la suma de una fila, he usado la fórmula `sumaFila <- sumaFila + mat[i * columnas + j]`, donde i es el índice de la fila y j es el índice de la columna. Esta fórmula calcula el índice del elemento en la matriz que corresponde a la i-ésima fila y la `j`-ésima columna.